# concurrent read that yield different result

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, vb.net, mariadb

I want to design a Point Of Sales application using VB6 or VB.NET.

This application needs to have different ID for each transaction. At the beginning of the transaction, the cashier will be shown the transaction ID as she/he begins the transaction for the first time. Different cashier must have different transaction ID.
Whats the best way to achieve this from database point of view ? Can it be achieved using tables/view/function in mysql ? How can i achieve this kind of mechanism ?

If i use `Select MAX(ID) + 1 GROUP BY cashier` for the subsequent transaction, then 2 concurrent request will have the same transaction ID. If i use an `INSERT ..ON DUPLICATE KEY update..` then i can not display the transaction ID on screen.

I have seen a similar application but i am not able to replicate the process of generating unique IDs. This app (based on JS) somehow manage to generate unique ID as each transaction begin without using `Select (MAX) id GROUP BY cashier`. its just using 1 sequence number as a reference.

The database i am using is mariadb, with table type innodb with repeatable read mechanism.

thanks

Comment: It's probably best to let the database take care of this.  Make the column an AUTO_INCREMENT column.

Comment: You are not the first person to be burned by simulating `AUTO_INCREMENT` instead of using it.  See also `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. if i use auto_increment, then the cashier wont be able to see the transaction id in advance. 
Ok, in the mean time, i will try the last_insert_id(). 

Is there any other possible way ? thanks

Comment: so far the best answer is using last_insert_id(). so i take james's respond as the answer. Coupled with [link] ronaldbradford.com/blog/last_insert_idexpr-the-lesser-known-usage-2007-09-12/ to modify its value [/link]. thanks alot

Comment: is using last_insert_id() slower than manually acquiring the id manually ? By manual i mean writing a function / stored procedure to SELECT and UPDATE a record that is used to track id. Eg : there is a tabel with 1 INT colomn. The function / stored procedure then read (select) this colomn and immediately increase its value by 1 (update). thanks for any advice...